# оптимизация запроса и таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется 3 таблицы: info, data, link, есть запрос для получения данных:

```
select *
from data,link,info
where link.info_id = info.id and link.data_id = data.id
```

Как можно оптимизировать данный запрос или таблицу?

Запросы для создания таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
        `desc` text default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `data` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        `date` date default NULL,
        `value` INT(11) default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `link` (
        `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `info_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: для начала прочитать про `JOIN` и их типы, а там уже и ответ на ваш вопрос сам всплывет. А в случае выборки всех записей без исключения думаю ни о какой оптимизации и речи не идет

Comment: @Victor join тут написан в сокращенной форме. MySQL строит абсолютно одинаковые планы как в случае использования join on так и в случае использования запятой и where

Comment: Для начала вам надо посмотреть с помощью explain plan текущий план выполнения запроса. А потом видимо построить недостающие индексы на поля по которым идут ссылки (foreign key, которые бы автоматом построили индексы вы же почему то в структуре таблиц не задаете). Но как сказали выше, вы все равно получаете с диска все 3 таблицы целиком, так что оптимизировать особо нечего. если бы были дополнительные условия отбора и/или вместо `*` была бы указана только часть полей, тогда уже есть что рассматривать

Comment: Чем вызвана необходимость оптимизации сферического запроса? А вообще для начала мигрируйте на InnoDB.

Comment: А почему вы решили что запрос сферический?....Такая организация данных сплошь и рядом.....когда у нас есть две таблицы..и связь многие ко многим...

Comment: Как минимум стоит добавить внешние ключи (`FOREIGN KEY`).

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.id, d.date, d.value, i.id, i.name, i.desc
from data d
join link l on l.data_id = d.id
join info i on i.id = l.info_id
```